# He started work at 9 and finished at 6. (4 variations)

Tags: sentence-construction, difference

Are all examples correct? Is the first example the most common in English? How do you choose which one is better to say or it doesn't matter here?

> He started work at 9 and finished at 6.

vs

> He started **his** work at 9 and finished **it** at 6.

vs

> He started **working** at 9 and finished at 6.

vs

> He started **to** work at 9 and finished at 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The big difference is that the first sentence has a strong implication of someone beginning their job, as in starting the day at their place of employment. The rest could all refer to any work that the person may be doing (cooking, cleaning, mowing the lawn, etc).

In addition, the second sentence in particular also has a strong connotation of referring to a single task or project. *His* work may be fixing his car, or baking a cake, or painting, for instance. On the other hand, saying working, or to work, just implies the beginning of an activity that might be considered work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a job then the first one is used most often, and the third one also sounds fine. If he's working on a task instead of a job then you could use 2 and 4